# Return array of objects with matching keys

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

For an exercise, I've written a function that, given an array of objects and a key (2nd argument), returns a new array of objects that contain all properties from a key. How'd I do?

```js
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];  
  var keys = Object.keys(source);
  var countMatchingProps = 0;
  var currentProp;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {    
    countMatchingProps = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
      // assigned to variable for a bit of readability.
      currentProp = keys[j];
      // if object contains key ->
      if(collection[i].hasOwnProperty(currentProp)){
        // -> then compare their values nad increment counter
        if(collection[i][currentProp] === source[currentProp]){
          countMatchingProps++;         
        }
      }  
      // if number of matched properties are 
      // equal to keys we can push current object to array
      if (countMatchingProps === keys.length) arr.push(collection[i]);
    }    
  }  
  return arr;
}

where([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 3 }], { "a": 1});
where([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better readability could be achieved using `array.filter`, since it creates the array for you and all you have to do is return `true` or `false`. No need to create an array, do the comparison and push yourself.

In the same way when checking for the values, `Object.keys` can be used with `array.every` to iterate through your constraints and see if each of the current item's keys match the constraint.

Also, I wouldn't call it `source`. It's not a source of anything. It's more of a "constraint" for your collection. So I'd call it that way instead.

In terms of performance, array iteration functions are slower than your average `for` loop (older APIs will tend to be more optimized). However, in terms of readability, these array APIs really shorten your code.

```js
function where(collection, constraint){
  // filter creates an array of items whose callback returns true for them
  return collection.filter(function(collectionItem){
    // every returns true when every item's callback returns true
    return Object.keys(constraint).every(function(key){
      return collectionItem.hasOwnProperty(key) && constraint[key] === collectionItem[key];
    });
  });
}

var a = where([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 3 }], { "a": 1});
var b = where([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })

document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(b));
```

The code can further be simplified by taking advantage of ES6 arrow functions. This removes the brackets (with one arg, the parens are optional), and the body can be an expression which would then be an implicit return value, eliminating `return`.

```js
function where(collection, constraint){
  return collection.filter(collectionItem =>
    Object.keys(constraint).every(key =>
      collectionItem.hasOwnProperty(key) && constraint[key] === collectionItem[key]));
}

var a = where([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 3 }], { "a": 1});
var b = where([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })

document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Comment: Nice. But maybe add a `collectionItem.hasOwnProperty` check to match OP's code

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Question though: in terms of performance, when you deal with huge collections (big json file or something) would you use loops like i did or it wouldn't have that much impact and stick with more readable way?

Comment: @MaciejKetus I'd stick with the more readable way until I can prove that it's causing a bottleneck. Use a profiler to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing your function into an `Object.prototype`, this also removes the need for a `collection` parameter:

Which would then become `this`.

```
Array.prototype.where(source) {
  var arr = [];  
  var keys = Object.keys(source);
  var countMatchingProps = 0;
  var currentProp;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {    
    countMatchingProps = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
      // assigned to variable for a bit of readability.
      currentProp = keys[j];
      // if object contains key ->
      if(this[i].hasOwnProperty(currentProp)){
        // -> then compare their values and increment counter
        if(this[i][currentProp] === source[currentProp]){
          countMatchingProps++;         
        }
      }  
      // if number of matched properties are 
      // equal to keys we can push current object to array
      if (countMatchingProps === keys.length) arr.push(this[i]);
    }    
  }  
  return arr;
}

[{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 3 }].where({ "a": 1 });
[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }].where({ "a": 1, "b": 2 })
```

---

- `countMatchingProps` should be declared in the `for` loop
- `arr`: don't sacrifice a few characters for readability: `array` is good.